# Proper way to input parameters for a library

Tags: c++, preprocessor-directive

I am writing a Matrix class with a small library of functions.

The class is able to implement both eager and lazy evaluation. I would like the user to choose if the class is always going to be eager or if it will be lazy when possible.

**Question:** Is there a standard way to provide this input?

I don't have much experience, so I haven't really seen if(and how) standard libraries or boost or others do it. Way that might be possible to use could be:

1. Have a static global variable and provide the user with a method to set its value.
2. Check for a preprocessor directive that if defined or not determines the code of the class to be compiled.
3. Other ???

Comment: You can use a template to switch between the different types of functionality if you want to do it at compile time.

Comment: @shuttle87 How would it be the use of the template? For example a numeric template parameter that, when an object is instanciated you set that parameter for that particular matrix?

Comment: You could implemented user choice as a policy, using templates. Read more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design or in A. Alexandrescus book "Modern C++ Design"

Comment: You can not do it statically in a library (at least it is a bad design decision) - provide both implementations, better use a a generalized matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is a header-only template library.

If you only want to provide a global switch (as opposed to a per-expression selection) this seems like a reasonable use of a macro switch.  I'd probably design the library such that your users can do

```
#define GREAT_LIBRARY_DISABLE_LAZY_EVALUATION
#include <great_library/matrix.hpp>
```

or even

```
$ cxx -DGREAT_LIBRARY_DISABLE_LAZY_EVALUATION file.cpp
```

Of course, you should make the more general option the default and not throw an error if the user doesn't select anything.

But this will only be useful if the macro being defined or not does not change what is a valid use of your library's types and functions and what not.  If your users find their initially working code causing pages of compiler errors after defining the macro, they will likely be upset.

Therefore, if it is not an “invisible” switch (ie affecting performance but not the semantics of the program at large), you'd better provide fine-grained control at each point of use.

Maybe with your templates taking an optional parameter.

```
great_lib::Computer<great_lib::EvaluationPolicy::Eager> eager_one;
great_lib::Computer<great_lib::EvaluationPolicy::Lazy> lazy_one;
auto some_result = eager_one.compute(arg1, ..., argN);
auto some_other_result = lazy_one.compute(arg1, ..., argN);
```

Or use [tag dispatching](http://www.boost.org/community/generic_programming.html#tag_dispatching).

```
auto some_result = great_lib::compute(arg1, ..., argN, great_lib::eager_tag);
auto some_other_result = great_lib::compute(arg1, ..., argN, great_lib::lazy_tag);
```

Finally, I don't think that something like

```
great_lib::set_evaluation(gerat_lib::EvaluationPolicy::Eager);
auto some_result = great_lib::compute(arg1, ..., argN);
great_lib::set_evaluation(gerat_lib::EvaluationPolicy::Lazy);
auto some_other_result = great_lib::compute(arg1, ..., argN);
```

will be very useful in a templated C++ library.  You'd really want your compiler to generate only the code that is needed for whatever option the user chooses but if that depends on a run-time value, it will have to generate code for both variants (and conditionals to select among them at run-time).  Even worse, you'd probably need some form of run-time polymorphism which we usually try to avoid in high-performance C++ code.